# How long does it take to break 128-bit key

Tags: passwords

Hmm, I was asking myself how to compute if we were given one day to try all possible keys for a 32-bit symmetric cypher, how long would it take us to break 128-bit key?

My calculations suggest:

> 2^128/2^32 = 2^98/365= 217063458943189966009709452.97534 years!

Is this correct?

Comment: You mean `= 2^96 / 365.242199`. If you are going to quote a large # of significant digits you should make sure the input matches. And you are ignoring the speed improvement that hardware will have in the intervening years. To mention just a few problems. Parallel processing anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we have one day to crack a 32-bit cypher. That means that it takes 2 days to crack a 33-bit cypher, 4 days to crack a 34-bit cypher, and so on. This means that it would take 2^128 - 2^32 or 2^96 days to crack.

[2^96 can be rewritten](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E96) as roughly 7.923 x10^28 or 79 octillion days, [or further broken down](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282%5E96%29%2F365.25) to 2.17 x 10^26 years or 217 septillion years.

Comment: Yeah, but what if we know that for a day we can try all possible keys of 32bit symetric cypher?

Comment: Guess I didn't properly understand the question. I edited my answer.